# Can I use Tag property to store it is name?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, .net-4.0

I am using below method to validate data within `textbox` in `groupbox`
so for improvement of user Feedback for example

message text `Please enter` **First Name**

where **First Name** is the label for textbox, so I used `Textbox.Tag` to store the name of `textbox` to achieve it since there is no link between the `Textbox` and it is `Label`

I search and found that I can use the `Tag` property to store anything but I wan to be sure of using it by the I told you about

Is there any problem with that ?

```
    public int ValidateData()
    {
        foreach (Control cont in GB_PatientInfo.Controls)
        {
            if (cont is TextBox)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cont.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("enter data " + cont.Tag, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
                    cont.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    cont.Focus();
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: [Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2): _"Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control."_ - legit, I'd say.

Comment: @Fildor yes I did read it but just to be 100% sure thanks for sharing your experience

Comment: Just one thing out of experience: You may want to actually store an object with a property "Name" in the Tag. You can have it implement some interface. If you later are urged to store something else additionally there, you can compose that object with another interface without 100 lines of code breaking.

Comment: The given answers are valid, but have you ever noticed how `ToolTip` lets you to set `ToolTip` for your controls at design-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's already mentioned in other answers, it's OK to use `Tag` property to store any kind of additional information about the control, including a display name.

But have you ever noticed how `ToolTip` lets you to set `ToolTip` for your control at design-time?

A `ToolTip`, `ErrorProvider` or `HelpProvider` are examples of extender provider components. They add some properties to the controls at design-time. You also can create such component for `DisplayName` by implementing [`IExtenderProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

**Example**

The following code shows you how easily you can create a component called `DisplayNameExtender`. When you drop an instance of this component on the form, then a new property will be added to design-time of controls, you can set the value to the property 
 at design-time: *DisplayName on diaplayNameExtender1*.

Then at run-time, whenever you want to get the value of `DisplayName` for a control, it's enough to find it this way:

```
var displayName = displayNameExtender1.GetDisplayName(control);
```

Here is the code for `DisplayNameExtender` component:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
[ProvideProperty("DisplayName", typeof(Control))]
public class DisplayNameExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private Hashtable displayNameValues = new Hashtable();
    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is Control && !(extendee is Form));
    }
    public string GetDisplayName(Control control)
    {
        if (displayNameValues.ContainsKey(control))
            return (string)displayNameValues[control];
        return null;
    }
    public void SetDisplayName(Control control, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            displayNameValues.Remove(control);
        else
            displayNameValues[control] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you have read, you can store any type that derives from object (i.e. everything) in the Control.Tag property so storing the name of a label is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the Tag property does not influence your application. You can store whatever you want in there with no problem.